# Call a function in a module after setup.py installation

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I've got a program/joke that needs a reasonably large data structure to operate, (a dictionary that takes a few seconds to construct) and I would like to create and pickle it into the installation dir when running `python setup.py install`.

`setup()` in `distutils.core` looks like it shouldn't exit, so I thought that I could just import my module and call the function after calling `setup()` in setup.py, but it doesn't seem to be working, even though installation *does* work.

This is what my setup.py looks like right now:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(...
    )

from phoneoops import utils

utils.get_hashed_dictionary(save=True)
```

Comment: Umm, why not create it *before* calling `setup` and pass it to the `data_files` parameter??

Comment: AndiDog if you make this an answer I'll accept it, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I created a dummy setup.py as:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup()
print 'after'
```

and my print statement prints just fine after running `python setup.py install`.
I tried an invalid command like `python setup.py xx`, and the after print didn't get called.

Are you sure it didn't raise an Exception or SystemExit?

When I modified this simple example to:

```
try:
    setup()
except SystemExit as e:
    print e
print 'after'
```

and ran `python setup.py xx`, the after statement ran fine.

***Edit:***
Agreed, @AndiDog, this is better (unless for some reason you *want* to swallow the exception):

```
try:
    setup()
finally:
    print 'after'
```

Comment: You should rather use a `finally` statement in your second example, so as to not swallow the error return code of the failed `setup()` call.

Comment: ma3204 you're right, I forgot that my PYTHONPATH has '.' at the beginning instead of the end, I was importing the source directory version instead of the destination directory.